# subject-verb agreement, which sentence is correct?

Tags: verb-agreement

*Which is correct and why? Thank you*

"Every male and female voter who **holds** the Tunisian nationality"

"Every male and female voter who **hold** the Tunisian nationality"

Comment: People *hold Tunisian nationality* - no article.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Usually, "every" implies _one_, as in "everyone". Also, the antecedent of your clause is singular,  so your first sentence sounds better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as *each* or *every* precedes a singular noun — you can't say "every words" — [the verb agrees with the noun in the singular](http://www.grammar.cl/english/all-every-each.htm).

> Every male and female voter who holds...

I would say *who holds Tunisian citizenship* rather than *the Tunisian nationality*.